# Cannot find all tile services hosted in my AGOL via REST

Tags: arcgis-online, tiles, arcgis-rest-api

I have already posted this problem to [geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/message/703818-arcgis-online-rest-page-limits-the-list-of-services-to-100-elements), but I thought it might be good to post it here, as people on GIS SE might have already seen such a problem (although I could not find any similar question).

Basically, I have more than 100 tile layers hosted on my ArcGIS Online, and I need to list them through the REST URL. However, some of my tiles are not listed there. It seems like the interface is limiting the number of elements to 100 (regardless the publication date and alphabetic order).

Moreover, I can confirm:

1. all the services I am not finding in the REST are working properly.
2. the server hosting the tiles is the same (or at least it should, as it is in the item's detail of AGOL)

Just to calrify: if from the AGOL interface, I enter in one of these tile layers' details and then click on visualize (at the bottom right part of the detail page), it opens up the details of the service via the REST interface. If from this same page I come back to the home of REST, where all services should be listed, the same service is not present there.

Comment: Do you login from the top right hand side on the REST page?

Comment: I can do that, but the only thing I get is a page with different colors, almost same elements. Just one more thing to interact with: a "catalog" button at the very bottom, which brings me to the same page I was before logging in.

Comment: Are you accessing the page with a token? if not it will just show the publicly accessible services. Another thing to check, if you published tiles from features they will be under services.arcgis instead of tiles.arcgis

Comment: I am accessing the REST with a valid token. Indeed; I can see also the protected services. Also, all the tile layers were prudeced from tile packages. The only strange thing I've noticed is that the number of the elements isd exactly 100, while I have 119 tile layers. I think it might be a limitation of the interface.

Comment: @RussRoberts Hi. Do you perhaps have suggestions regarding this issue? I will really appreciate it. Otherwise thanks anyway for the comments.

Comment: When you look under your organization do the Tile layers have (Hosted) around them. Possibly could have some setup that are duplicates or referencing another service. You could also check out using ago-assistant or under the org status page to find all your tile results and see what ones could be missing from the REST page.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, all Tile Layers are hosted (I can see it within brackets and I knew they were). If I go to "my organization->status->contents",  I can see the list of all the Tile Packages, but no Tile Layers (neither one), and those names that are not showing up in the REST are present here (again, as Tile Package).

Comment: So the tile layers you can see under the Status >content tab > On the chart click layer > Click Map Service. for this you can see all the tile layers (1 yr date range limit). Or try this search under your org and see if it returns the 119 and see if any of the missing ones from the REST throw an inaccessible error when you go to the service from item detail typekeywords:”Map Service”,"Hosted Service"

Comment: Hopefully, I got you correctly. I went in my organization tab, then contents, clicked on "Layer" in the bar chart, then on "Map service". I look for the layer I don't find in the REST, find it and click on its name. A popup with some info shows up. If in this window I click on "Other details" (hopefully the translation is correct, my page is in Italian), I see the ususal "item details" page, from where I can click on "Visualize" at the bottom right and open the REST of the item. As I wrote in the question, from here I can go back to the REST home and this same tile service is not listed.